# как посчитать количество строк в БД таблице с заданным значением `rec_id`?

Tags: python, sqlite

нужно подсчитать количество строк в ветке `rec_id` со значением например `1`
и вывести это значения '`print()`'

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(rec_id) from ТАБЛИЦА where rec_id='1'`

Comment: а если ещё нужно просуммировать значения ветки 'voice' там где rec_id = 1  ?

Comment: меняешь COUNT(rec_id) на COUNT(voice)

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim только не COUNT(voice) а SUM(voice) если речь идет о сумме

Comment: SUM(voice) он же подсчитает всю ветку, а нужно считать лишь те строки где rec_id = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подсчета количества строк следует использовать метод COUNT():

`SELECT COUNT(rec_id) from ТАБЛИЦА where rec_id='1'`

Для получения суммы, можно использовать метод SUM():

`SELECT SUM(voice) from ТАБЛИЦА where rec_id='1'`